# Magento 2.0.9- Cannot login to magento admin

Tags: magento-2.0

I logged into magento 2.0.9 admin, enabled the caches , but after sometime when refreshed admin panel is not working. Showing like in the image below. How to get into the admin panel. Thanks in advance.
[image]